Help identifying PWM controller SMPS ICs and other
Can anyone help find a suitable replacement for the following IC?

I have a SMPS few boards SMPS with two different revisions.
IC size SOT23-6
One revision uses 61A51a or 61G52 this IC has:

pin 1 (connected to voltage divider: + 100k | 22k - )
pin 2 GND
pin 3 FB  (connected to optocoupler)
pin 4 (connected MOSFET 12N65 source,) maybe sense
pin 5 Drive  (connected to MOSFET gate via transistor W2A 42)
pin 6 VCC

On the other revision, the board changed only the PWM IC and the correspondent traces.
The PWM IC is marked 6853K45.  It looks like the CR6853, pin compatible to SG6848 and others.

GND pin 1
FB pin 2
RI pin 3
Gate pin 6
VCC pin 5
Sense Pin 4


Welcome! For component identification, a photo would help a lot.

Will post ASAP @winny

It's probably an On-Bright OB2361MP PWM controller.

There are some variations in the markings when you search for pictures online, but here is one from taobao that shows similar markings:

(Source: taobao.com)
